# how to rotate data labels for charts in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I want to rotate the data label to 90 degrees in column chart. I used the code written below but its not working.

```
    <fx:Style>
     @font-face{
        src: url("/assets/MyriadWebPro.ttf");
        fontFamily: myMyriad;
         embedAsCFF: false; 
    } 

    @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";

    mx|ColumnSeries {
        labelPosition:outside;
        labelRotation:90;
    }     

     mx|ColumnChart {
        fontFamily: myMyriad;    
    } 
</fx:Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the labelRotation for the axis renderers.

```
<mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
            <mx:AxisRenderer labelRotation="45"
                             styleName="myStyleNoCFF" axis="hAxis"/>
</mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
```

Edit :

Set the showLabelVertically to true in the column chart.

```
 <mx:ColumnChart id="columnChart"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        showLabelVertically="true">
```

Comment: I am asking about data label which are shown on top of each column of colun chart. The above solution is for axis labels.

Comment: If you want the label displayed by a ColumnSeries to be rotated, you don't set a "labelRotation" property like you would on an AxisRenderer.  Instead, you set the showLabelVertically property on the ColumnChart.  I don't know why it's not there on the series.

Comment: Are you referring to data tips instead of labels?

Comment: No, I'm referring to the datalabels. An example can be see @ http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/01/23/displaying-the-labels-vertically-in-flex-columnchart-control/